# In PHP, Is there a way to get a subset of an array whose keys match the values in another array?

Tags: php, arrays

Currently, I am using this function `get indicies` to collect the key/values from an array for an array of keys stored as values in another array:

```
function get_indicies($haystack,$needle_names = array()){

    $needles = array();
    foreach($needle_names as $needle_name){ 
        if( isset($haystack[$needle_name]) ) $needles[$needle_name] = $haystack[$needle_name];
    }
    return $needles;
}
```

There are a ton of array functions in php, is there a way that I can, in class-scope, do this more efficiently, and user more of the built-in php functions?

Comment: @shaddyx I don't think it will work: keys of one array are values in another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$subset = array_intersect_key($haystack, array_flip($needleNames));
```

This is often used under the name `pluck` or similar as helper function.

```
function pluck(array $array, $keys) {
    if (!is_array($keys)) {
        $keys = func_get_args();
        array_shift($keys);
    }
    return array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
}

var_dump(pluck($array, array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')));
var_dump(pluck($array, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'));
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see this. this is exactly the anwer to my question

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't preserve the order of the array of keys in the resulting array; I'm pretty sure, given this constraint, there is no way to do with without using, minimum some version of 'array_map' with a callback function or a for-loop; barring that, though, again, thanks.